# Updating serviceworker configuration using gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, service-worker

I am trying to super-optimize a [PWA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_app) by combining and minifying as much as I can. My application is based mostly on a [google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/) on service workers - and as such I have code such as this in my service worker:

```
var filesToCache = [
  '/',
  '/index.html',
  '/scripts/app.js',
  '/styles/inline.css'
];

self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});
```

I have a `gulpfile.js` which, among other things uses [`gulp-smoosher`](https://github.com/gabrielflorit/gulp-smoosher) to inline my css during build:

```
<!-- smoosh -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/inline.css">
<!-- endsmoosh -->
```

Which works great - it inlines my css directly into the HTML - however clearly my `filesToCache` in my serviceworker now has an entry which wont exist in the build

```
var filesToCache = [
  '/',
  '/index.html', 
  '/scripts/app.js',
  '/styles/inline.css' // <!--- this shouldn't be here in the build
];
```

Is there any options, using a gulp task or otherwise (perhaps some sort of config for this which can be updated on build) to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by making the following changes.

- Move the `filesToCache` variable to its own json file - `filesToCache.json`
- Update my service worker to load that file in during `install`
- Use `gulp-json-editor` to manipulate the file on build.

---

Code in gulpfile

```
const jsonEditor = require('gulp-json-editor');

// snip

gulp.task("filesToCache", function(){
  var out = folder.build;
  return gulp.src(folder.src + "filesToCache.json")
              .pipe(jsonEditor(function(json){
                json.splice(json.indexOf("/styles/inline.css"),1);
                return json;
              }))
              .pipe(gulp.dest(out));
});
```

---

Code in service worker

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return fetch("/filesToCache.json").then(function(response){
        if(response && response.ok){
          return response.json()
        }
        throw new Error("Failed to load files to cache for app shell")
      })
      .then(function(filesToCache){
        console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell', filesToCache);
        return cache.addAll(filesToCache);        
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.error(error)
      })
    })
  );
});
```

---

Hope this helps someone in future!